# Does the .NET JITter perform optimization of primitives in mathematical expressions?

Tags: c#, optimization, jit

I have some C# code that performs some calculation involving primitive data types, such as:

```
public sealed class Calculation
{
    private readonly int a, b, c;

    public Calculation(int _a, int _b, int _c)
    {
        this.a = _a; this.b = _b; this.c = _c;
    }

    public int DoCalculation(int rfactor, int lfactor)
    {
        return (a / rfactor) + (b / lfactor) + ((a/b)*(rfactor+lfactor));
    }
}
```

If {a,b,c} were compile time constants the expression in the DoCalculation(...) method could be hugely optimized at the CIL level.  I am wondering if the JITer will optimize the DoCalculation(...) method similarly to the compile time constant optimizations given the "readonly" hint.

Comment: Try profiling with and without `readonly`. In Release mode etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is not a great one, but yes, this kind of optimization certainly happens.  At more than one level, the C# compiler gets a shot first.  It will evaluate simple expressions with literal values and replace them with the result.  Also the way that it can detect overflow at compile time.

The jitter optimizer does this too, normally as a result of *inlining* methods.  But that won't happen for your DoCalculation() method, it is too complicated to allow inlining.  But a trivial one like:

```
    public static int DoCalculation(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }
```

Will certainly get inlined and optimized.  Like Console.WriteLine(Calculation.DoCalculation(4, 5)) generates:

```
00000003  call        5927D408 
00000008  mov         ecx,eax 
0000000a  mov         edx,14h                      // <=== here
0000000f  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx] 
00000011  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax+38h] 
00000014  call        dword ptr [eax+14h]
```

Note how the result, 4 * 5 = 20 = 0x14 got precomputed.

There are no hard rules for when exactly the method can get inlined and how involved the expression can be before the optimizer gives up.  This is subject to change and depends on the kind of jitter (x86 vs x64 vs ARM).

If this code lives deep inside your critical path and a profiler told you that it is responsible for 80+% of the execution time (don't skip the profiler!) then it is can be worth your time to tinker with the method and see what you get.  Debug the Release mode build and be sure to allow the optimizer to run.  Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" option.

Small changes can have big effects, feels pretty good when you get to double the speed of your code with a seemingly trivial edit.  Or not and you get nowhere after a day of trying, no guarantees.  But you'll certainly develop a "feel" for what kind of code runs well, an experience and insight that is *very* valuable.

Answer (score 4):

No, because the variables are not constants. Their value is not known at the time of jitting. Being readonly does not change the fact that their runtime value is unknown and can differ between instances.

Comment: Not all JIT optimizations require full knowledge at the time of jitting though, frequency analysis being one. (important edit)

Comment: The jitted code must deal with all possible instances of `Calculation`. The fields can be different for each instance. The values can be anything at all at runtime (think of an instance created through reflection).

Comment: Is there any documentation that explicitly states that all instances must be the same?  Some Java JITers don't have this restriction.

Comment: This isn't very accurate.  Those variables certainly *can* be constant, it depends on the how the constructor+method is called.  When they both get inlined and the method arguments are constant then those variables are constant as well.  The jitter knows how to do that.